# Set a global standard for to_char in Postgres

Tags: linux, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.5

Just like the title says, I would like to set the global default for the to_char function in Postgres. I considered this:

```
to_char(date_test, SELECT datestyle FROM settings)
```

But that seems hacky. Any better ideas?

**Explanation:** I want my database to present the date in a user settable format. So far, this is what I came up with. But I would appreciate a more fluent way if possible. The Postgres [OUTPUT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-datetime.html#INTERVAL-STYLE-OUTPUT-TABLE) option does not support all formats.

**Edit:** I already formatted the date the way I want it. This is an open source app, and I want a clean way for other people to format the date. Preferably server side, since there have been requests for all server side computation to support selectable frontends.

Comment: Just write your own function, say, `my_date_to_char()` and use whatever format you like.

Comment: @GordonLinoff See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems dangerous to let the user freely choose the date format, it would be better to give a choice of formats.

There is no “default format” in PostgreSQL. I would format the dates in the application rather than in the database, but you can keep the selected format in a variable and feed it to `to_char` whenever you need.

Comment: Would you mind expounding on why it is dangerous to let the user format his dates? SQL injection, maybe?

Comment: Ok, it is not dangerous, I was exaggerating. But I bet that if you let users enter a date format, which follows complicated rules, there will be lots of pilot errors resulting in illegible dates. Giving fewer choices can make life simpler.